# Hubspot WordPress Plug in - ignore a certain page - is_page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, hubspot

So essentially I have Hubspot plug in on Wordpress all is well however Hubspot tracks all pages on the site regardless. I dont want Hubspot to track a shop page lets say it's slug is spares-and-repairs I have tried putting this simple bit of code into the footer of the theme and trst running it but it's still inserting the Hubspot tracking Java into the footer of the spares-and-repairs page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

```
<?php if (is_page('spares-and-repairs')) { ?>
<?php } else { ?>

<!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->

<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: _"into the footer of the theme"_ - could be due to what the second note here says then, I suppose? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#notes

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now I copied thst piece of code off something someone else wrote so how would I encorporate that reset code into it as I'm not good with php